# Boxes are tripping if I insert text in them

Tags: html, css

*** RESOLVED BY INTENSE RESEARCHING ***

[[DOWNLOAD CODE, NO COPYRIGHT](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/41330678/NoCopyright.rar) =)] ***.rar file ( always scan before opening .rar - F4LLCON***

Problem is that without text the boxes are placed 2 on each row, but with text the boxes
appear under each other with spacing. To get the text in the boxes I used `<style>` in `<head>`.

How can I FIX this annoying problem?

IMAGE: [image: LINK]

*Without the p and h3, both echo text will appear under the box and not in the box [image]*

Code:

```
<style>
        p {
        position:relative;
        top:-240px;
        left:180px;
        }
        h3 {
        position:relative;
        top:-270px;
        left:30px;
        }
</style>
```

and

```
<div class="offers">
    <div class="content_box">
        <?php
            while($products = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo '<img src="includes/images/content_box.png" border=0/>';
            //  echo "<h3>" . $products['products'] . "</h3>";
            //  echo "<p>" . $products['description'] . "</p>";
            }   
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

RESOLVED BY DOING:

```
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
#title{color:red; padding-bottom: 240px; padding-left: 25px;}
#desc{color:blue; padding-bottom: 135px; padding-left: 5px;}
</STYLE>
</head>
```

and

```
<div>
    <?php while($products = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?> 
        <table align="left" background="includes/images/box.gif" width="473" height="285">
            <tr>
                <td width="35%" height="100%" id="title">
                    <?php echo $products['products'] . "&nbsp"; ?>
                </td>
                <td width="70%" height="100%" id="desc">
                    <?php echo $products['description'];?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <?php
            }   
        ?>
</div>
</body>
```

This might be easy for some, but I'm new to this.
Now working correctly.

Thank you for giving me directions and Thank you Google and Stackoverflow for so much help =)

[image]

Comment: Can you show us all the CSS, including for the `div.content_box`?

Comment: H3s are block elements by default and, I think, 100% width. Try .content_box h3{ display:inline-block; } (or just inline). Anyway, I think that it's the h3 causing the wrapping -- try maybe also explicitly defining it's width.

Comment: Hello, I tried that but nothing happend.. I'll post a LINK in the question. includes css/connection to database/php.

Comment: I managed to fix it, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am asuming that content_box.png is the background for the box right?

instead of including it in a  create it in the background of a div with a class like this

CSS:

```
    .product_box {
         bacground:url(includes/images/content_box.png);
         width:xxxpx; /* the width of conrent_box.png */
         height:xxxpx; /* the height of conrent_box.png */
         position:relative;
         float:left;
    }
```

php:

```
    <?php 
        while($products = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<div class="product_box">';
        //  echo '<img src="includes/images/content_box.png" border=0/>';
            echo "<h3>" . $products['products'] . "</h3>";
            echo "<p>" . $products['description'] . "</p>";
            echo '</div>';
        }   
    ?>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello, thank you for the code, but it does not show any image at all when I do this. I have posted a LINK to everything, you can download the code....